# Не могу получить доступ к файлу. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, файлы

Я получаю путь к файлу, сохраняю в переменную.(Путь корректный, я проверял). Далее пытаюсь получить его по пути уже в другом классе. Путь до файла не меняется. Однако приложение файл уже не находит. Что делать?

```
File bookFile = new File(FileName);
```

Причём, если я запускаю своё приложение на 6 андроиде, то всё отлично работает. Если на 8, то файл уже не находится. Надеюсь на помощью:)

Comment: наверное приложение, которое вы разрабатываете в IDE Android Studio не может получить доступ к файлу, а не сама AS, да?

Comment: pavlofff, да, именно так

Comment: Получите разрешение на доступ к чтению с памяти: [ознакомьтесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172519/oreo-write-external-storage-permission)

Comment: @Sandman, не помогло:(

Comment: Используйте FileProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то пригодится. Решение нашёл. На андроидах 8+ uri.getPath() вернёт путь, но работать с ним невозможно через File. Используйте сам URI. Тогда на любом андроиде всё будет хорошо.